# How to handle custom paging system threw Get and model info passed to controller at the same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table with loads on entry, theres 10 entry by page, and around 130 total page.

how can I handle an action on the same view while still retaining the paging in memory ...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
        <label>All Logs since :</label> <input id="startDate" name="startDate" class="datepicker" type="text" value="@Model.option.startDate.Value.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")" />

<input type="submit" />
        }
```

When this is submitted, I want the table to be filter base on the start Date. But if the user click on a page link, I need this research result to override the default setting in my view. heres the action in my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
            MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();

                model.option = new LogOption();
                model.option.numberOfResultPerPage = 10;
                model.option.startDate = (method to set default date)
                model.option.startPageIndex = id ?? 1;

                *** call to service with the model.options as filter and set my table's column info  and retreive the logs total in a custom class ( model.listing ) *** 

                model.totalPage = model.listing.TotalPages;

            return View(model);
```

now when the user submit a new Date, I do the exact same thing, but with a small difference, which is to set the default date to something like that :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LogOption mod)
    {

        model.option.startDate = mod.startDate;
     }
```

the problem is that if after the startDate filter have been modified, if the user click to change the page from my table, the get action is called again, and I dunno how to handle the overriding of the original default setting. can i do that in a cleaner way without having to set the info in session ?

I guess I need to pass the model along with the get info, but I havent been able to do it .

```
 [HttpPOST]
    public ActionResult Index(MainViewModel mod, int? id)
    {
     }
```

but my MainViewModel is always null when I do this, so I dont know how to get both information aside from saving it in session, but I was told to avoid that and that it was possible to do it other way

Comment: Does your MainViewModel have a parameterless constructor? I agree with the last approach: Have 1 GET action that takes the model and other parameters.

Comment: @Cam I cant do it, my mainviewmodel is always set to null ... I didnt set any contructor in it yet, its mainly just 3 custom object ( user profile, list of logs, and filter options ) and the 3 custom object doesnt have any contructor set up either ( well user profile is the one set by default by mvc4, so it might have, havent worked it yet )

Comment: Maybe this will help, but then maybe not: Remember to set model type in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realise I was trying to save my GET info into the POST action ... which is kinda stupid logic

Answer (score 1):

The type of problem you are facing is *state persistence problem*. There are numerous ways to solve this issue (because HTTP is stateless by design), but the most simple are:

- use cookies to save startDate
- use session (will use cookies in most cases)
- use wrapper model around your entity that includes filtering information

I'll show the latter:

```
class DateWrapper 
{
    public Date StartDate {get;set;}
    public MainViewModel Model {get;set;}
}
```

In your view you can check the `null == StartDate` and depending on the result, generate link that includes filtering information (either as GET parameter or via another route).

Comment: a new urgent command was given to me before I could dig in further, I'll let you know when I go back to work on this project if I could implement it this way

Comment: Sorry I just I made an error in my question, the problem I had is that I was trying to have the page id from the GET and save that variable when a POST action was made ... I realise I just have to get rid of the POST value and force the user back to page 1 if he tried to filter the search result.